# AWS IoT Core - How to enable infinite reconnection after connection loss (MQTT)

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, raspberry-pi, aws-iot

I am using **aws-iot-device-sdk-js-v2** primarly on Raspberry PI and for testing purposes on Windows 10.
I am connecting to AWS like this:

```
const client_bootstrap = new io.ClientBootstrap();

let config_builder = iot.AwsIotMqttConnectionConfigBuilder.new_mtls_builder_from_path(config.aws.cert_path, config.aws.key_path);

config_builder.with_certificate_authority_from_path(undefined, config.aws.root_ca_path);

config_builder.with_clean_session(false);
config_builder.with_client_id(config.aws.thing_name);
config_builder.with_endpoint(config.aws.iot_endpoint);

const mqttConfig = config_builder.build();

const client = new mqtt.MqttClient(client_bootstrap);
connection = client.new_connection(mqttConfig);

shadow = new iotshadow.IotShadowClient(connection);

thingName = config.aws.thing_name;

return connection.connect();
```

Everything works perfectly when there is connection. If i disconnect from internet, after sometime (20-30 seconds) i will get `interrupt` event with the following error:

```
    CrtError: aws-c-io: AWS_IO_SOCKET_CLOSED, socket is closed.
        at MqttClientConnection._on_connection_interrupted (/home/mstupar/device/node_modules/aws-crt/dist/native/mqtt.js:334:32)
        at /home/mstupar/device/node_modules/aws-crt/dist/native/mqtt.js:114:113 {
      error: 1051,
      error_code: 1051,
      error_name: 'AWS_IO_SOCKET_CLOSED'
    }
```

If I connect to internet after this interrupt, i will get an unhandled exception with the following stacktrace:

```
################################################################################
Resolved stacktrace:
################################################################################
0x00007fc3193b781b: ?? ??:0
0x00000000000b1383: s_print_stack_trace at module.c:?
0x00000000000128a0: __restore_rt at ??:?
0x00007fc31c4bef47: ?? ??:0
0x00007fc31c4c08b1: ?? ??:0
node() [0x95c589]
node(napi_acquire_threadsafe_function+0x27) [0x9cf1e7]
0x00007fc3192f1931: ?? ??:0
0x00000000000b4306: s_on_connection_resumed at mqtt_client_connection.c:?
0x00000000000de34c: s_packet_handler_connack at client_channel_handler.c:?
0x00000000000dee9e: s_process_read_message at client_channel_handler.c:?
0x000000000011269d: s_s2n_handler_process_read_message at s2n_tls_channel_handler.c:?
0x0000000000113bbe: s_do_read at socket_channel_handler.c:?
0x00000000001141f2: s_on_readable_notification at socket_channel_handler.c:?
0x0000000000110a5a: s_on_socket_io_event at socket.c:?
0x000000000010bb9a: s_main_loop at epoll_event_loop.c:?
0x0000000000177c1b: thread_fn at thread.c:?
0x00000000000076db: start_thread at ??:?
0x00007fc31c5a1a3f: ?? ??:0
################################################################################
Raw stacktrace:
################################################################################
/home/mstupar/device/node_modules/aws-crt/dist/bin/linux-x64/aws-crt-nodejs.node(aws_backtrace_print+0x4b) [0x7fc3193b781b]
/home/mstupar/device/node_modules/aws-crt/dist/bin/linux-x64/aws-crt-nodejs.node(+0xb1383) [0x7fc3192f1383]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x128a0) [0x7fc31c8928a0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0xc7) [0x7fc31c4bef47]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x141) [0x7fc31c4c08b1]
node() [0x95c589]
node(napi_acquire_threadsafe_function+0x27) [0x9cf1e7]
/home/mstupar/device/node_modules/aws-crt/dist/bin/linux-x64/aws-crt-nodejs.node(aws_napi_queue_threadsafe_function+0x11) [0x7fc3192f1931]
/home/mstupar/device/node_modules/aws-crt/dist/bin/linux-x64/aws-crt-nodejs.node(+0xb4306) [0x7fc3192f4306]
/home/mstupar/device/node_modules/aws-crt/dist/bin/linux-x64/aws-crt-nodejs.node(+0xde34c) [0x7fc31931e34c]
/home/mstupar/device/node_modules/aws-crt/dist/bin/linux-x64/aws-crt-nodejs.node(+0xdee9e) [0x7fc31931ee9e]
/home/mstupar/device/node_modules/aws-crt/dist/bin/linux-x64/aws-crt-nodejs.node(+0x11269d) [0x7fc31935269d]
/home/mstupar/device/node_modules/aws-crt/dist/bin/linux-x64/aws-crt-nodejs.node(+0x113bbe) [0x7fc319353bbe]
/home/mstupar/device/node_modules/aws-crt/dist/bin/linux-x64/aws-crt-nodejs.node(+0x1141f2) [0x7fc3193541f2]
/home/mstupar/device/node_modules/aws-crt/dist/bin/linux-x64/aws-crt-nodejs.node(+0x110a5a) [0x7fc319350a5a]
/home/mstupar/device/node_modules/aws-crt/dist/bin/linux-x64/aws-crt-nodejs.node(+0x10bb9a) [0x7fc31934bb9a]
/home/mstupar/device/node_modules/aws-crt/dist/bin/linux-x64/aws-crt-nodejs.node(+0x177c1b) [0x7fc3193b7c1b]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x76db) [0x7fc31c8876db]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x3f) [0x7fc31c5a1a3f]
```

Is it possible to avoid AWS_IO_SOCKET_CLOSED with additional configuration?
How should I properly reconnect? Is there some automatic way like socket.io has.
The device should be able to run at least 1 day without restart. In that day, multiple connection losses may occur. Process restart with systemd is not good solution for this case because i am running some other modules in the same process that should not be affected with connection loss.

Is there any additional configuration needed for MqttClientConnection?
Should I call some functions from interrupt to resume connection manually?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This issue has been fixed in latest aws-iot-device-sdk-js-v2 API releases.

Comment: How did you deploy your app on windows? I cannot package my node app using aws crt with pkg.